# Deriving from base class but not calling base method

Tags: c#, xna, oop, inheritance

I am very new to C#, XNA, and OOP. This is my question: I have an abstract class called Sprite. Sprite handles position and drawing from the sprite sheets, from its update and draw methods, for my other automated and user controlled classes. I have another class that I need to create that also uses a sprite sheet but not in the same way. The sprite sheet in this case shows the texture in 5 states, from whole to destroyed, and I am going to write the update method for it so that when a missile collides with the texture, then and only then does the next frame of the sprite sheet get drawn. Is there a way that I can have this class, called bunker, be a child of the sprite class but never call the update method from the parent? Or should I just make it a seperate class altogether? Thank you for bearing with my noobish question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that like using interfaces,abstract classes, etc. But you can use virtual methods.
You can make the update method of Sprite class "virtual" like this:

```
public  virtual void update()
{  // code for sprite update
}
```

And then in bunker class you  should override update method and change it from what it was in sprite class :

```
class Bunker: Sprite
{
...
public override void update()
{//here your update code 
//different
 //from  base(Sprite) class}
}
```

Comment: One question to be clear, in the bunker update method, am I still including the line `base.Update();` ? I assume that I need to and it gets sorted out with the virtual keyword...  I am going to write it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sinux1 if you want sprite.update() method to be called in addition to bunker.update(), you should add base.update() in bunker update method.

Comment: But that would mean that the base update would also run, right? I don't want that . Thank you.

Comment: @Sinux1 It seems like you want the `Sprite` class to be `abstract` and then have your "not-Bunker" objects be another class inheriting from `Sprite`. You would then have all code which is common to all sprites in `Sprite` and all object-specific code in the derived classes.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, I made Sprite abstract. I've got some automated enemies and a player who all derive from the sprite class. I appreciate all the help. This SE is awesome.